# DolphinDB error when calling udf: “The object date is neither a XDB connection nor a function definition.”

Tags: user-defined-functions, dolphindb

server version: `2.00.8 2022.09.28`

I define a function `myFunc` in DolphinDB as follows. The definition part and each line of code in the function body can be executed successfully. But error occurs when the script is run:

Server response: 'myFunc("20230118", t) => myFunc: tmp = select * from t where date(dt) == date => The object date is neither a XDB connection nor a function definition.'

```
dt = 2023.01.18T04:01:51.100 2023.01.19T04:01:51.000 2023.01.19T04:01:51.900
sym = ["IBM", "MSFTN", "GOOGS"]
value = 1..3
t=table(dt, sym, value)

def myFunc(day, t){
    date = temporalParse(day, "yyyyMMdd")
    tmp = select * from t where date(dt)=date
    return tmp
}

myFunc("20230118", t)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works after just replaced the variable `date` to `dateParsed`:

```
def myFunc(day, t){
    dateParsed = temporalParse(day, "yyyyMMdd")
    tmp = select * from t where date(dt)=dateParsed
    return tmp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is reported because a variable named “date” is defined in the function body, and the built-in function `date` is called later. When the function is parsed, `date(dt)` cannot be recognized as a function as the variable is parsed first. Thus it is not recommended to define variables with the same name as built-in functions or other keywords.

The script can be corrected to:

```
def myFunc(day, t){
    myDate = temporalParse(day, "yyyyMMdd")
    tmp = select * from t where date(dt)=myDate
    return tmp
}

myFunc("20230118", t)
```